# Zooming issues with Force Directed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've generated a D3 visualization (a force directed graph) that requires zooming and panning. I've got 2 problems however when it comes to zooming, and I can't find any decent examples on how I might overcome these problems:

1. The first problem is I've followed all the examples I can find about zooming, which involves adding groupings and adding a rectangle to ensure that the entire area is zoomeable. If I style the rectangle a slightly opaque blue then I get SVG that looks like this when I zoom out:

[image]

The problem with this is that I can zoom in/out absolutely fine while I've got my mouse over the blue rectangle area. The problem is I want this to be fully opaque, which means that when I zoom right out, it's very easy to place the cursor outside of this box and then you're unable to zoom in. Is there a way I can make the SVG itself zoomeable or pick up on these events?

This is how I go about generating the various layers and the zoomed function:

```
function zoomed() {      
  group2.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

svg = d3.select(target)
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .append("svg");

group = svg.append('svg:g')
           .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', zoomed))
           .on("dblclick.zoom", null);

group2 = group.append("g");
rect = group2.append('svg:rect')
          .style("opacity", 0.3)
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height);
```

2. The second problem I have is that I'm trying to automatically size my text based on this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1846692 example. When I've tried this however I seem to be getting text that renders really poorly. It seems to suffer from:

   - Being difficult to read
   - Not appearing contained within the circle
   - Being so small the entire thing compresses (image 2)

[image]

[image]

```
var texts = planets.append("text")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
                .style("font-size", "24px") // initial guess
                .style("font-size", function(d) { 
                  return Math.min( 2 * d.size, (2 * d.size - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength() * 24) + "px"; 
                })
                .attr("dx", function(d) { return -d.size; })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("fill", "white");
```

I thought that SVG would just handle this, I understand that some of the font-sizes can come out small, but if you zoom in should that not all sort itself out?

I've got a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/vo7Lpefs/22/ to demonstrate.

Comment: For your first problem, [can you just not zoom the rect](http://jsfiddle.net/vo7Lpefs/24/) (so it won't shrink)?

Comment: @Mark that is a really good point, although it'll be an increase zoom to make it expand on zoom out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not yet managed to work out a resolution to my first issue (regarding the zooming box) however I did manage to track down the text rendering issue.

This was actually because the each circle/node had a stroke property to provide the white border. This was also applying to the text element, and when the font was very small the stroke was much larger than the overall fill of the text. Removing the stroke from the text elements ensured that they rendered even when very small.